# Typescript - Type X is missing the following properties from type X

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following code doesn't work:

```js
import * as blessed from "blessed"

const mainScreen: Screen = blessed.screen({})
```

I get a type error from Typescript, which is:

```
fack.ts:4:7 - error TS2739: Type 'Screen' is missing the following properties from type 'Screen': availHeight, availWidth, colorDepth, orientation, pixelDepth

4 const mainScreen: Screen = blessed.screen({})
        ~~~~~~~~~~
```

It looks like the `Screen` type is incompatible with itself? How is this possible?
I'm using Node 14.15 and my dependency versions are:

```js
{
    "blessed": "^0.1.81",
    "@types/blessed": "^0.1.17"
}
```

Why doesn't this pass type checking?

Comment: Ah yes! It looks like `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts` contains an interface called "Screen". But wat do?

Comment: I'm answering now :)

Comment: Basically, import the type you want from the right package.  Though this package seems to not export `Screen`  directly so you have to import the whole `Widgets` namespace and extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see this sort of error it's almost always because you have two types from two different packages which just so happen to share the same name.  Here you have a function which returns a type `blessed.Widgets.Screen` and you are assigning it to the type `Screen` which is included in the global namespace by the typescript DOM typings.

Since your `Screen` is the one from "blessed" rather than the one from the DOM, you need to import the type definition from the blessed package.

```
import * as blessed from "blessed"
import {Widgets} from "blessed";

const mainScreen: Widgets.Screen = blessed.screen({});
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! An alternative solution, though less generally useful, is to remove the duplicate type by configuring TypeScript to not include the other `Screen`, such as with `"lib": ["es2019"]` inside `compilerOptions`. I prefer your answer because it prevents duplicates from becoming an issue at all with more highly specified type annotations.